# understanding on code snipet IPCamera for android

Tags: java, android, sockets, nanohttpd

Anyone please help me understand this code. this is taken from the IPCamera from android which i take from the googlecode. the code that i was trying to figure out was:

```
public NanoHTTPD( int port, File wwwroot ) throws IOException
    {
        myTcpPort = port;
        this.myRootDir = wwwroot;
        myServerSocket = new ServerSocket( myTcpPort );
        myThread = new Thread( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while( true )
                            new HTTPSession( myServerSocket.accept());
                    }
                    catch ( IOException ioe )
                    {}
                }
            });
        myThread.setDaemon( true );
        myThread.start();
    }

private class HTTPSession implements Runnable
    {
        public HTTPSession( Socket s )
        {
            mySocket = s;
            Thread t = new Thread( this );
            t.setDaemon( true );
            t.start();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream is = mySocket.getInputStream();
                if ( is == null) return;
```

Things that i want to know. please tell me if what i understand is wrong:

1- `myServerSocket.accept()` what this code will return? boolean value as if true or false?

2- `InputStream is = mySocket.getInputStream();` Input stream is to get the byte stream. but what the program read on mySocket. From what i understand, it reads on the port number. What it has to do with mySocket with to get the byte?

I am really sorry if my understanding is completely wrong as socket is not my knowledge. please help me to understand more on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's ServerSocket's [accept() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)

> Waits for an incoming request and blocks until the connection is opened.

and

> Returns
>
> the connection representing socket.

And here's [getInputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29) which

> Returns an input stream to read data from this socket.

You might want to read up on sockets and streams.

Here's Java's tutorial [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: my question on getInputStream is what the program read on mySocket? next question is accept method. it returns connection representing socket. meaning does it return true if it receive the connection? I mean, what is exactly this program return?

Comment: @sarabrown What it read was an input stream and the tutorial should clear a lot of things up. The accept method returns a Socket object not a boolean. It `Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it`. And yes, it uses the port you specified (meaning accept listens on that port).